# inline javascript inside a href element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

inside html I want to render current url with # as addition inside a href element

Desired result would be for example: `<a href="/Home/Contact#">MyLink</a>`
so I tried with

```
<a href="javascript: getUrl();">My link</a>
<script>
    function getUrl() {
        return window.location.pathname + '#';
    }
</script>
```

On page load this actually loads up this url from the script and as a result give me a blank page with `/Home/Contact#`content, once again I just to render this url inside my a href element, not to execute that link on page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify the links with some kind of common marker (such as a class or a `data-*` attribute), for instance:

```
<a class="the-common-class">My link</a>
```

...then once you have the base path (or just at the end of the HTML, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag) update their `href` attribute:

```
$(".the-common-class").href(window.location.pathname + "#");
```

If they should have different hash fragments, the `data-*` attribute would probably work better:

```
<a data-hash="something">My link</a>
```

then:

```
$("a[data-hash]").href(function() {
    return window.location.pathname + "#" + this.getAttribute("data-hash");
});
```

or if you want more jQuery:

```
$("a[data-hash]").href(function() {
    return window.location.pathname + "#" + $(this).attr("data-hash");
});
```

(Note: Don't use `.data("hash")`, that's not what it's for.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
 function getUrl() {
    $(this).attr('href', window.location.pathname + '#');
}
```

Comment: Users will be frustrated by the first click not working.